# Having problems getting this pulldwown menu to display any sub menus of the main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I need to create a pull down menu and and several submenus off of the main pull donw. I tried this exact code from the tutorial site i can not see any of sub menus when I click on the main menu. This is very frustrating.
I have anynother applcication I am just placing this code as the first items in the html body. I there anything special I need to link in.
I am linkinjg in require.js jquery.js jqueryui.js.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? (Anything in the console?) 
Try https://jsfiddle.net/5t14e0y1/

Comment: Thanks for fiddle. It works when it is all by itself but it does not when I have other html code below it in my layout. It seems like it will not go over the top of other items when you click the top level button of the pop up menu